# как заменить сообщение с фото на сообщение без фото telebot

Tags: telebot

Как изменить сообщение с фото и подписью на обычное сообщение с текстом, и наоборот? Используя библиотеку Telebot

Answer (score 0):

```
def photo(message):
    if message.content_type == 'photo':
        photo_id = message.photo[3].file_id
        text_photo=message.caption
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo_id)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,text_photo)
```